# How to use a socks 5 proxy in socket.io

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to use a socks 5 proxy in a socket.io node.js client, and i already tried this:

```js
var io = require('socket.io-client')

var SocksProxyAgent = require('socks-proxy-agent');
var agent = new SocksProxyAgent('socks5://165.227.174.249:33080');

const socket = io('http://localhost:3000', {agent: agent})

socket.on('connect',() => {
console.log('connected')
})
```

and it just hang up and did nothing.
Any ideas of why?

Comment: Did you get the answer? I'm kinda interested in the same thing.